# Counting combinations without destroying type

Tags: r, data.table, combinations, factors

I wonder whether someone has an idea for how to count combinations like the following in a better way than I've thought of.

```
> library(lubridate)
> df <- data.frame(x=sample(now()+hours(1:3), 100, T), y=sample(1:4, 100, T))
> with(df, as.data.frame(table(x, y)))
                     x y Freq
1  2012-06-15 00:10:18 1    5
2  2012-06-15 01:10:18 1    9
3  2012-06-15 02:10:18 1    8
4  2012-06-15 00:10:18 2    9
5  2012-06-15 01:10:18 2   10
6  2012-06-15 02:10:18 2   12
7  2012-06-15 00:10:18 3    7
8  2012-06-15 01:10:18 3    9
9  2012-06-15 02:10:18 3    6
10 2012-06-15 00:10:18 4    5
11 2012-06-15 01:10:18 4   14
12 2012-06-15 02:10:18 4    6
```

I like that format, but unfortunately when we ran `x` and `y` through `table()`, they got converted to factors.  In the final output they can exist quite nicely as their original type, but getting there seems problematic.  Currently I just manually fix all the types afterward, which is really messy because I have to re-set the timezone, and look up the percent-codes for the default date format, etc. etc.

It seems like an efficient solution would involve hashing the objects, or otherwise mapping integers to the unique values of `x` and `y` so we can use `tabulate()`, then mapping back.

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's `data.table` version that preserves the column classes:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(df, key=c("x", "y"))
dt[, .N, by=key(dt)]
#                       x y  N
#  1: 2012-06-14 18:10:22 1  8
#  2: 2012-06-14 18:10:22 2 10
#  3: 2012-06-14 18:10:22 3  8
#  4: 2012-06-14 18:10:22 4  8
#  5: 2012-06-14 19:10:22 1  6
#  6: 2012-06-14 19:10:22 2  8
#  7: 2012-06-14 19:10:22 3  6
#  8: 2012-06-14 19:10:22 4  6
#  9: 2012-06-14 20:10:22 1 15
# 10: 2012-06-14 20:10:22 2  5
# 11: 2012-06-14 20:10:22 3 12
# 12: 2012-06-14 20:10:22 4  8

str(dt[, .N, by=key(dt)])
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  12 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ x: POSIXct, format: "2012-06-14 18:10:22" "2012-06-14 18:10:22" ...
#  $ y: int  1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
#  $ N: int  8 10 8 8 6 8 6 6 15 5 ...
```

**Edit in response to follow-up question**

To count the number of appearances of **all possible combinations** of the observed factor levels (including those which don't appear in the data), you can do something like the following:

```
dt<-dt[1:30,]  # Make subset of dt in which some factor combinations don't appear

ii <- do.call("CJ", lapply(dt, unique))  # CJ() is similar to expand.grid()
dt[ii, .N]
#                      x y N
# 1: 2012-06-14 22:53:05 1 8
# 2: 2012-06-14 22:53:05 2 7
# 3: 2012-06-14 22:53:05 3 9
# 4: 2012-06-14 22:53:05 4 5
# 5: 2012-06-14 23:53:05 1 1
# 6: 2012-06-14 23:53:05 2 0
# 7: 2012-06-14 23:53:05 3 0
# 8: 2012-06-14 23:53:05 4 0
```

Comment: Very nice.  I keep *almost* switching wholesale to `data.table` but never really making the leap.  Maybe I should.

Comment: Actually - when I run that code using 3 keys `x,y,z` instead of just two, it complains about `object '.N' not found`.  In my real data I have 3 keys, but I'd boiled it down to 2 for this question, thinking that wasn't important.  Is there something about `.N` that makes it unavailable with 3 keys?

Comment: Oops - my bad, it works fine.  I copied a variable name wrong.

Comment: @KenWilliams -- Me too. Now that Matthew Dowle has implemented `:=` with `by`, it's more tempting than ever. I feel like that's a killer feature that'll really increase `data.table`'s appeal, as it allows such a natural and compact syntax for split-apply-combine summaries.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to keep all combinations of the keys like `table()` does, and like you can get with `ddply(.drop=FALSE)`?  I do want zeroes there for combinations that don't occur in the data, but I'm not seeing in the docs how to accomplish that.

Comment: @KenWilliams -- Great question. I just edited my post with an example of how to get a tally that includes those zeroes-frequency combinations as well.

Comment: The `lapply()` part of that solution seems extremely slow, which surprises me.  `system.time( lapply(tb[,c(x,y,z)], unique) )` reports 87.70 elapsed seconds when `tb` is a `data.table`, but `system.time( lapply(df[,c('x','y','z')], unique) )` takes 0 seconds when df is the equivalent `data.frame`.

Comment: Oh, I did it wrong - it should have been `lapply(tb[,list(x,y,z)], unique)` for the `data.table` code.  MUCH better now. =)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ddply`

```
library(plyr)

ddply(df, .(x, y), summarize, Freq = length(y))
```

If you want it arranged by `y` then `x`

```
ddply(df, .(y, x), summarize, Freq = length(y))
```

or if column ordering is important as well as row ordering

```
arrange(ddply(df, .(x, y), summarize, Freq = length(y)), y)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that `ddply()` was actually the first way I wrote this.  Unfortunately it's WAY slower than the `table()` method.  Which makes sense - `table()` just tabulate counts, whereas `ddply()` has to actually extract all the related data and feed it to the function.

Comment: I did not realize efficiency was the aim. `data.table` is definitely the way to go. I am currently converting myself from `plyr` to `data.table`.

Comment: Yes, I should have been more clear in my question.  I'm glad to see this solution with `summarize` though, I didn't know about that function.  FWIW, it also works with `ddply(df, .(x, y), nrow)` but the column name isn't quite as nice.